# How to use UUIDs in Neo4j, to keep pointers to nodes elsewhere?

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

I figured out thanks to some other questions that Neo4j makes use of ids for its nodes that could get recycled in case of node deletion.

That's a real concern for me as I need to store a reference to my node in another database (relational this time) in order to keep some sort of "pinned" nodes.

I've tried using this https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid to generate them automatically, but I did not succeed, all my queries kept running indefinitely.

My new idea is to make a new field in each of my nodes that I would manually fill with a UUID generated by NodeJs package `uuid` through `uuid.v4()`.

I also came across the concept of indexing multiple times, which is totally unclear to me, but it seems that I should run this query:
`CREATE INDEX ON :MyNodeLabel(myUUIDField)`

If you think that it doesn't make sense at all don't hesitate to come up with another proposition. I am open to all kinds of suggestions.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider using the APOC library's `apoc.uuid.install` procedure.

Definitely create a unique constraint on the label and attribute you are going to use. This will not only create an index but also guarantee uniqueness of the attribute in the label namespace.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (mynode:MyNodeLabel) ASSERT mynode.myUUIDField IS UNIQUE
```

Then call the `apoc.uuid.install` procedure. This will create uuid's in the attribute `myUUIDField` on all of the existing  `MyNodeLabel` nodes and on any new ones.

```
CALL apoc.uuid.install('MyNodeLabel', {addToExistingNodes: true, uuidProperty: 'myUUIDField'}) yield label, installed, properties
```

NOTE: you will have to install APOC and set `apoc.uuid.enabled=true` n the neo4j.conf file.

Comment: Thanks :-) I'll give it a try as soon as tomorrow. Could you try to explain what exactly is an index please? Or point me to some good resources. I could easily find how to activate them in the manuals but it is unclear regarding what they are and do exactly.

Comment: An index is just some extra data stored about the order of a range of values that enables faster retrieval of valuess in that range.

Comment: Like in math? I could say `myField` values are within the range [0.0, 10.0]

Comment: I ran across a Null Pointer Exception, I had to append `poc.uuid.enabled=true` in my `neo4j.conf` to make `apoc.uuid` work. You should add this precision in your answer to help future users. Anyway thanks heaps for your help!

Comment: Also I noticed that I have to call the procedure whenever restart Neo4j's service. Is it the expected behavior? And is there any way to automate this if I have to do it every time?

Comment: wanted to add automatic uuids to nodes without installing a 3rd party library and this did the trick, thanks!